# Quote a C++ MACRO parameter

Tags: c++, macros

I have the following *template*:

```
variable = config["variable"] ? config["variable"].as<type>() : default;
```

I want to create a macro to have this done for me faster, since writing this many times becomes boring. I would try something like:

```
#define CONFIG_PARAM(config, key, type, alt) config["key"] ? config["key"].as<type> : alt;

title = CONFIG_PARAM(root, "title", std::string, "")
```

It's obvious that that wouldn't work. How can I get this done?

Comment: #define AUX_VALUE(x) x █
#define QUOTATION_VALUE() " █
#define STRINGIFY(x) QUOTATION_VALUE()AUX_VALUE(x)QUOTATION_VALUE() █

#define CONFIG_PARAM(config, key, type, alt) config[STRINGIFY(key)] ? config[STRINGIFY(key)].as<type> : alt; █
#define CONFIG_PARAM2(config, key, type, alt) config[key] ? config[key].as<type> : alt; █
title = CONFIG_PARAM(root, title, std::string, "") █
title =CONFIG_PARAM2(root, "title", std::string, "") █   "█" is a line feed.

Answer (score 9):

To use strings inside a macro use this: `#define str(s) #s` This tells, that the argument has to use as a string

This is how to use `##`

```
 #define COMMAND(NAME)  { #NAME, NAME ## _command }

 struct command
 {
   char *name;
   void (*function) (void);
 };

 // a call
 struct command commands[] =
 {
   COMMAND (quit),
   COMMAND (help),
   ...
 };

 // this expands to:
 struct command commands[] =
 {
   { "quit", quit_command },
   { "help", help_command },
   ...
 };
```

Comment: what if `NAME` contains quotes already?